# calendar with the current date

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to add a calendar in my ASP.NET application with the current date. I used this one:

```
asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server"  SelectedDate="<%# DateTime.Today %>"
```

But I want the current date to be highlighted for example with yellow colour. Is there a way to do that??
Thank you

Comment: I don't like downvoting questions.  This is the first question in a long time I was seriously contemplating it.  There should be at least a minimal amount of research done, this is such a basic thing that has already been answered a bunch of times on here and the simple search http://www.google.com/search?q=calendars+in+asp.net reveals 55 million results with the first 5 showing everything you need for downloading, setting up and tutorials for using the calendars in ASP.NET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may checkout the [Calendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.aspx) control. There's also an [AJAX Calendar](http://www.asp.net/ajax/videos/how-do-i-configure-the-aspnet-ajax-calendar-control) control.

Answer (score 0):

or you can pick jquery ui calendar,

- [jQuery UI Datepicker ASP.NET Control](http://www.west-wind.com/jqueryweb/jqueryDatepicker.aspx)
- [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/jquery-ui-datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

Which calendar do you use? If it does not matter, I recommend [jQuery UI Calendar](http://jqueryui.com), it's flexible, few clicks themeable & easy to learn. You can add it with just few line of code, for example

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

And current date is selected by default. See [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) page for demo and code samples.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a Calender control to ASPX page it highlights todays date automatically, I don't think you need any code to highlight it, just set the "TodayDayStyle-BackColor" property to your required colour.